# Why is this Ruby going destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following Ruby form:

```
.search_client_users
    .main_form.client_emails
      = simple_form_for(:domainNameSwap, url: { action: "update" }, html: { class: "search_form", method: :put }) do |f|
        .input-row
          = f.input :oldDomain, :label => "Old Domain Name", input_html: {name: 'search_term'}
        .submit-row
          .row
            .col-xs-5
              .submit
                = f.submit "Update domains", id: "submit", :class => "btn btn-primary submit"
```

relevant bits of routes.rb:

```
resources :client_emails, :path => 'client_emails', :controller => 'client_emails' do
  collection do
    get 'lookup'
    get 'client_list'
    put 'update_emails'
  end
end
```

The form mostly works as intended, but when I click submit, it goes to: `http://localhost:3000/admin/client_emails/update` which seems reasonable, but displays the error:

```
Missing template admin/client_emails/destroy, admin/base/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

What is routing this to destroy? In the controller, it's definitely going to the destroy method not the update method (both exist)

There's probably some other info I need to show, but I'm not sure what it is...

Adding controller code. Probably way more than necessary...

```
class Admin::ClientEmailsController < Admin::BaseController
  DEFAULT_SEARCH_RESULTS_LIMIT = 300

  def index
    @cep_landing_page = ClientLandingPage.find_by_description("CEP")
    @yt_landing_page = ClientLandingPage.find_by_description("YouthTruth")
    @roster_data_instructions = ClientLandingPage.find_by_description("YouthTruth Roster Data Instructions")
    puts "index"
  end

  def new
    @client = Client.new
    puts "new"
  end


 def update
    puts "BAR"

    newDomClients = Client.where("email like '%"+ newDom + "'")
  end

    redirect_to admin_clients_path
  end

  def destroy
    puts "foobie"

    puts params
  end

  def client_list
    clients = SearchClientUsers.matching(params[:search_term])
    @clients = clients.limit(search_results_limit)

    @search_results_count_message = if params[:search_term].blank?
      "Showing #{@clients.count} of #{clients.count} client users"
    else
      "Showing #{@clients.count} of #{clients.count} client users matching the search criteria"
    end

    render layout: false
  end

  private

  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :organisation, :assigned_team)
  end

  def search_results_limit
    Integer(ENV['CLIENT_SEARCH_RESULTS_LIMIT'] || DEFAULT_SEARCH_RESULTS_LIMIT)
  end

end
  def user_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

Comment: Do you have any associated controller code? The view code doesn't dictate which template is rendered. It can only reference partials.

Comment: GAH! thanks @tadman! I have an extra "end" statement in my update.

Comment: Wait, no I didn't never mind

Comment: Remember `log/development.log` will tell you precisely which routes are being exercised, what controller and action are being executed, and what templates are being used.

Comment: Do you know what is `domainNameSwap` ? Because your form is referencing this object like if it was a model / controller to whcih the update method should be called. Obviously the tags `.main_form.client_emails` says it is about client emails. If you are trying to pass the form to `resources :client_emails ... put 'update_emails'` action you should be more explicit as it is a custom route. You should add the full path, in the form_for, not only the action. Also this action needs be a `member` not a `collection` unless you pass the `client`or `client_email` id in a hidden field.

Comment: I thought that if you just put a symbol in the reference object, it will just create  a new object with that name in the params. That appears to be what it's doing... It **IS** going to the client_emails_controller... it's just going to "destroy" instead of "update"...

Comment: I have learned that the outer div seems to be controlling this! (changing the name removed the behavior.... but also removed other important behavior...)

Comment: It appears to be because Ihave two divs? that seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be because of the combination of the `.main_form` and the `.search_client_users` If I either remove the `.main_form` entirely, on turn it from `.main_form.client_emails` to `.main_form_client_emails` (which are completely equivalent, I understand) it appears to work...

If someone can explain WHY that works, or what else is going on here, I'll approve that answer... But currently I'm just going to leave this here for future generations...